# Image rotation is slow on touches moved

Tags: iphone, image-rotation, touchesmoved

**I have written a program that will rotate my imageView as i want (CW or ~CW).
And it is working fine. 
but it is responding very slowly, I want it to respond quickly...
can you please help me out of it?
Thanks in advance...!**

**Following is my code------------------------**

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {

        UITouch * touch = [[event allTouches]anyObject];
        CGPoint prevLoc = [touch previousLocationInView:self];
        CGPoint loc = [touch locationInView:self];

        if (isRotating) {

            float prevAngle = atan2(prevLoc.y-self.center.y,
                                    prevLoc.x-self.center.x);

            float newAngle = atan2( loc.y-self.center.y,
                                  loc.x-self.center.x);
            float finalAngle =angle+(newAngle-prevAngle);


            //Apply new transform
            CGAffineTransform rotateTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(Angle);

            self.transform=rotateTransform;
            angle = finalAngle;

        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"responding very slowly"*? Is it laggy and jittery (i.e. a performance issue), or rotating smoothly but not as fast as you would like?

Comment: its not jittering, but it is not rotating as fast as i want
(As i move my finger, it starts moving but not with my finger,it lags in displacement)

Comment: Read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780536/implementing-touch-based-rotation-in-cocoa-touch?rq=1) and see if it helps you.

Comment: Hey... finally i am satisfied...Thanks for your help..
Actually it helped me with that static function...

Comment: @PartiallyFinite: Can you please help me with this question....[link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16986857/1195286)